# Const mismatches: 2 overloads have no legal conversion for 'this' pointer

Tags: c++, vector, constants, this-pointer

I'm getting this weird error:

> error C2663:
>   'sf::Drawable::SetPosition' : 2
>   overloads have no legal conversion for
>   'this' pointer

I think it has something to do with const mismatches but I don't know where, or why.
In the following code I have a vector of shapes and sprites, and when trying to access one of the vectors shapes and calling one of its functions I'm getting the error.

```
std::vector<sf::Shape> Shapes;
std::vector<sf::Sprite> Sprites;

bool AddShape(sf::Shape& S){
    Shapes.push_back(S); return true;
};
bool AddSprite(sf::Sprite& S){
    Sprites.push_back(S); return true;
};

private:

virtual void Render(sf::RenderTarget& target) const {                
    for(unsigned short I; I<Shapes.size(); I++){
        Shapes[I].SetPosition(
            Shapes[I].GetPosition().x + GetPosition().x,
            Shapes[I].GetPosition().y + GetPosition().y);
        target.Draw(Shapes[I]);
    }
    for(unsigned short I; I<Sprites.size(); I++){
        target.Draw(Sprites[I]);
    }
}
```

**How can I fix this?**

Comment: Obviously it's not obvious.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

`Render` is declared with a `const` after the parameters. This means it does not change its object. Which means, that all of the object's member variables are considered constants within `Render`, as changing their state means changing the containing object. Assuming `Shapes` is a member variable, and that `SetPosition` does change the shape (i.e. not declared as `const`), you cannot call it within a `const` member function.

So, remove the `const` from `Render` and you'll be fine (you fix your logic, in case it must be const).

Comment: He can't remove the const; he's deriving from a base class that presumably put that const there to begin with.

Comment: @Nicol Bolas, how do you know? The OP doesn't say anything about the class that contains `Render`, does he? And if he does and I've missed that, he'll just have to change the content of `Render`. You can't change member variables inside a `const` member function (unless you want to hack your own code, and surprise its users).

Comment: @Nicol Bolas, well, I didn't know that... But my point still stands - he should change his implementation. It actually makes sense - why would rendering an object change its state? In order to confirm with the base class he's inherited, rendering should not change the object's state. Without me deep diving into the implementation, a possible solution could be declaring a local vector of Shapes, which will be set and passed to `Draw`. that might not be efficient, but it will solve the const mismatch (local variables are allowed to be changed within const member functions).